# TCP sockets bottleneck with InnoDB/Debian?

Tags: performance, innodb, linux, mysql-5.1, tcpip

We have a big mysql performance issue on a production environment with 18 "front" servers sending mysql queries to a unique mysql server. We are using Redis on each front server for a number of things, but there is still one important job done only on the mysql server. So we have 5 processes on each of the 18 servers, sending big select queries to our mysql server. The where condition is changing for each query because the result is cached on each ad server in a redis cache and reused when the where condition would be the same. Since we have a different caching system, this query is using the SQL_NO_CACHE option.
There are other queries running on the system, many small writes and a few large reads and writes, but most of the load comes from this query.
The query is quite big: it uses 17 tables, some of them with several million records, the query can return up to 5000 records, each record is quite large. But the query is well optimized and runs in 0.02s when the load is low. With our usual system load, the query runs on average in 1.5s. We are handling query queues on each ad server and monitoring the average time a query stays in the queue before it’s executed. Usually a query stays in a queue about 2 minutes. But lately, with our traffic growing and after adding a few servers, the average execution time increased to 2s and the time-in-queue exceeded 20 minutes. So we decided to try some fine tuning...

Our mysql server is a 24 cores running Debian 6 with 64G RAM and MySQL 5.1 (InnoDB only). Since the CPU and RAM were not used at 100% we thought there could be another bottleneck. We noticed that we had many TCP sockets on the server in the time_wait state and thought that maybe the number of TCP sockets available was a bottleneck so we changed from using a single IP address to using 5 IP addresses for our mysql server. We also changed the TCP sockets lifetime from 2 hours to 2 minutes. After 2 hours, the performance increased very nicely: the query average execution time went down from 2s to 0.5s and the time-in-queue went down from 20 minutes to 10 minutes… but after one and a half day the execution time went back up to 15s and the time in queue to 20 minutes. We have tried reversing all the changes in order to go back to the previous situation but it didn’t work.

We are looking for a senior DBA with good experience of InnoDB/Debian who could help us fix this performance issue, then help us find the bottlenecks and optimize the tunning of our mysql server.

Here is our my.cnf file:

```
# Example MySQL config file for very large systems.
#
# This is for a large system with memory of 1G-2G where the system runs mainly
# MySQL.
#
# You can copy this file to
# /etc/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is @localstatedir@) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#

# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#password       = your_password
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
skip-name-resolve
skip-federated
default_time_zone       = 'Europe/Paris'
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog = 1
transaction-isolation=READ-UNCOMMITTED
#innodb_force_recovery =  4
#skip-grant-tables
#skip-networking
#replicate-ignore-db    = mysql
user            = mysql
port            = 3306
old_passwords       = false
max_connect_errors  = 10000
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql/prod
#basedir        = /usr
tmpdir          = /var/tmp
#skip-locking
# LC 28-06-2012 Passage a 300M apres calcul des index des table MyISAM :
# select sum(INDEX_LENGTH/1024/1024) from information_schema.tables where engine="MyISAM";
key_buffer      = 300M
max_allowed_packet  = 128M
# Modif LC 28-06-2012 car pas assez de tables cachees 80000 -> 160000 -> 40000 -> 20000 -> 1000
# Ajout de table_open_cache le nouveau nom du parametre
#table_cache        = 6000 
table_open_cache    = 24000 # max_connections * 18 ( 18 tables used in targeting query ) + delta
table_definition_cache  = 512
sort_buffer_size    = 32M
read_buffer_size    = 10M
read_rnd_buffer_size    = 3M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 1M
thread_cache_size   = 64
query_cache_type    = 1
query_cache_limit   = 128M
query_cache_size    = 512M
query_cache_min_res_unit = 8K
join_buffer_size    = 4M
max_connections     = 200   
low_priority_updates    = 1 # JBN : On the slave, updates are more important than reads
concurrent_insert   = 2
wait_timeout        = 300 
# Try number of CPU's*2 for thread_concurrency
thread_concurrency  = 48
#thread_concurrency = 24

#
#Temporary tables
#
# Modif LC 11-06-2012 car trop de tables temporaires 1024 -> 8192
#tmp_table_size          = 1024M
#max_heap_table_size     = 1024M
tmp_table_size          = 8192M
max_heap_table_size     = 8192M
max_tmp_tables      = 64

#
# log paths
#
log-error       = /var/log/mysql/error.log
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
slow_query_log      = 1
long_query_time     = 1 
log-queries-not-using-indexes

# This is a master server in a master/slave replication (id=1 + binlogging)
server-id       = 1

#log_bin                 = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 1
max_binlog_size         = 1G
#binlog_do_db           = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db       = include_database_name
#relay_log              = mysql-relay
#relay_log_space_limit  = 50G

# Fulltext search
ft_min_word_len     = 3


#
# Language variables
#
character-set-server    = utf8
collation-server    = utf8_general_ci
language        = /usr/share/mysql/english

#
# InnoDB parameter
#

ignore_builtin_innodb
plugin-load=innodb=ha_innodb_plugin.so;innodb_trx=ha_innodb_plugin.so;innodb_locks=ha_innodb_plugin.so;innodb_lock_waits=ha_innodb_plugin.so;innodb_cmp=ha_innodb_plugin.so;innodb_cmp_reset=ha_innodb_plugin.so;innodb_cmpmem=ha_innodb_plugin.so;innodb_cmpmem_reset=ha_innodb_plugin.so
innodb_file_format=barracuda

# Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#innodb_data_home_dir = @localstatedir@/

innodb_data_file_path       = ibdata1:512M:autoextend
innodb_table_locks      = OFF
innodb_support_xa       = 0
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode    = 2             # WARNING : binlog-format = ROW IS MANDATORY
# binlog_format                   = row
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 2

#innodb_log_group_home_dir = @localstatedir@/
#innodb_log_arch_dir = @localstatedir@/
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high

# LC 28-06-2012 innodb_buffer_pool_size 12G -> 24G -> 18G
# KHA 29-06-2012 -> 12G ( 18G too big ) 
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 48G
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 32M

innodb_log_file_size        = 128M
innodb_log_buffer_size      = 8M
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    = 250
innodb_file_per_table
# LC 12-06-2012 innodb_thread_concurrency 64-> 24
innodb_thread_concurrency   = 12
#innodb_thread_concurrency  = 64

# LC 17-06-2012 Ajout innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT pour voir l'impact perf au niveau RAID hardware
# A tester
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet      = 16M

# Language variables needed for backup / restores
default-character-set   = utf8

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

# Language variables needed for backup / restores
default-character-set   = utf8

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 256M
sort_buffer_size = 256M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 256M
sort_buffer_size = 256M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout

# Cyb tuning
[mysqld]
log-warnings=2 # logs more information to log-error
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

UPDATE:

We have discovered the cause of the performance degradation: a partner started sending us much more detailed data, increasing significantly the number of rows returned by our query and the number of row examined. In order to avoid this we archived old data and removed it from the 2 main tables and we replaced the LIMIT 5000 by LIMIT 500. Our service is a bit degraded but we can live with that, the average query response time dropped down to 5s, which is acceptable and allows us to work.

Now that we understand that our changes were not responsible for the performance drop, we are going to re-apply them (more innodb threads and mySQL listening on multiple IP addresses).

Comment: As you seem to be able to understand the answer from your comment, would you be willing to improve the Google translation? And consider voting on or accepting the answer if it solved your problem of course :)

Comment: I reviewed the Google translation. I don't have enough reputation for voting up this useful reply which doesn't fully solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Hello, do you have munin graphs for your MySQL server and for at least one front-end server? In the cases I have come across, the problem was rarely coming from the `TIME_WAIT`. On a problem of large number of connections on Apache, the solution was to create multiple instances. Recompiling the kernel to reduce the duration of `TIME_WAIT` changed nothing.

Regarding the MySQL configuration (but without seeing any graphics or accessing the servers it's difficult to say), I would not put `query_cache_limit` so high, have you tried with `innodb_thread_concurrency` set to `0` and `thread_concurrency` lower, at 8-10?

Does the server swap? Have you set the swappiness to 0? Depending on the RAM usage, `innodb_buffer_pool_size` can be further increased according to the volume of your data. Try increasing `innodb_buffer_pool_instances` to 4 or 8, it's an improvement in some cases.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
We are going to check if the server swaps and to try changing query_cache_limit, innodb_thread_concurrency, innodb_buffer_pool_size and innodb_buffer_pool_instances.
Do you think hoard could bring some improvement?
Regarding sockets in time_wait state, our goal is not really to free them earlier but to increase the max number of TCP sockets available (55k by IP address for us) by handling multiple IP addresses. We are going to try that again.

Comment: Can you contact me by private message, for example with your viadeo account ?

Comment: While this answer seems to have helped the OP, because they can speak French, this answer isn't very useful to just about every other reader, present and future. Can you please consider translating the answer to English so that it matches the language the question was originally asked in? Thanks.

Comment: We discourage private exchanges of "connect me with your XYZ account so I can assist you offline". The intent of this network is to make the internet better by sharing as much information on solving a problem as possible.